# .net smtp listener

Tags: .net, smtp

Is there a way for using .net to create a console app. or service to listen for SMTP messages over a certain port?

I need to create a middle tier object that will capture and process smtp messages. That is to say i want smtp messages sent and picked up by this listener and then broken down to its basic components and persisted to a sql server DB.

If there is a off the shelf solution even better. I was not able to find one as I scurried the web.

Note: smtp sender will be a web app on the network, as well as exchange. The listener will be assigned some port so all smpt traffic on this port will be designated for my particular application.

Comment: So basically you want to write an SMTP server? Why not have a regular SMTP server simply forward the mails to your app? Postfix and sendmail are both perfectly capable of forwarding the entirety of an email to external programs.

Comment: @marc: do they scale to handle 10, 100, 1000 messages per second? and how will my app be able to parse the email to extract from, to, body, attachments...? sorry if i was unclear. i am lookign for a ,net code sample on this if possible.

Comment: sendmail's been handling literally trillions of emails over the years. It'll scale from 0 to whatever the hardware can sustain. However, if you're doing this to receive custom messages, why bother with the SMTP overhead? Nothing says you can't write your own protocol.

Comment: @marc: Postfix and sendmail are both unix based and i need it to run on windows.

Comment: IIS has an smtp module you could use, though I have no idea if you can have it pipe the incoming mails to external programs. But again: If you're running the SMTP on a custom port, then why bother using SMTP?

Comment: @marc. i am using smpt because there are compliance apps that monitor smtp. so i am plugging into existing architecture rather than diving into a custom interaction into 3rd party systems for legal, compliance, review... applications already in place and can not be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how good it is, but there's an [SMTP server example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/smtppop3mailserver.aspx) at CodeProject.

What you're asking for is more than "listening for SMTP messages." SMTP is a two-way communication protocol.  Sending an email involves multiple packets being passed between client and server.  I wouldn't recommend trying to write one yourself unless you don't have anything better to do.

I'd suggest that you take a look at the SMTP module that comes with IIS. It will deliver emails to a directory in the file system, which your program can monitor and process.